# Something wrong with facebook real-time updates

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get page feed updates in my php project. So.

**1)** i have created test page for facebook account and got {page_id}
**2)** i have created app account and got {app_id} and {secret}
**3)** created registration procedure

```
$appId  = Yii::app()->facebook->appId;
$secret = Yii::app()->facebook->secret;
$access_token = $appId."|".$secret;
Yii::app()->facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

$callbackURL = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/callbackfb";

$result = Yii::app()->facebook->api("/".Yii::app()->facebook->appId."/subscriptions",'POST',
    array(
      'object' => 'page',
      'callback_url' => $callbackURL,
      'fields' => 'feed',
      'verify_token' => $this->verifyToken));
```

and callback

```
$method = Yii::app()->request->getRequestType();

if($method == "GET")
{
  // answering to fb, that this is callback url, it is working and all ok
  Yii::log("GET request to callback","warning","facebook");
  if (isset($_GET["hub_verify_token"]) && $_GET["hub_verify_token"] == $this->verifyToken && isset($_GET["hub_challenge"]))
    $this->_sendResponse(200,$_GET["hub_challenge"]);

  else $this->_sendResponse(400,"Fail");

} elseif ($method == "POST")
{
  Yii::log("POST request to callback","warning","facebook");

  // my update code
}
```

**4)** called registerfb (all ok - sucessfully registered and i can see 'GET' request to my callback in log file)
**5)** after maked {temp_access_token} in graph explorer with "manage_pages" and "publish_actions" permissions.
**6)** request http://graph.facebook.com//{user-id}/accounts?access_token={temp_access_token} gave me {page_access_token}
**7)** by request https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/tabs?method=post&app_id={app_id}&access_token={page_access_token} i has installed my app to the page

But. Something going wrong. When i post to page, there is no request from facebook. I tried to post on the page through graph api, but no updates received.

The question is where a made a mistake.

Comment: Your step 7) is wrong – subscribing to page updates is not done via `/{page-id}/tabs` any more, but via `/{page-id}/subscribed_apps` – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2_new_features, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribedapps/